# Iterating through sites with Python Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

How do I iterate through sites with Scrapy? I'd like to extract the body of all sites that match `http://www.saylor.org/site/syllabus.php?cid=NUMBER`, where NUMBER is 1 through 400 or so.

I've written this spider:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from syllabi.items import SyllabiItem

class SyllabiSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'saylor'
    allowed_domains = ['saylor.org']
    start_urls = ['http://www.saylor.org/site/syllabus.php?cid=']
    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=['\d+']), 'parse_syllabi')]

    def parse_syllabi(self, response):
        x = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        syllabi = SyllabiItem()
        syllabi['url'] = response.url
        syllabi['body'] = x.select("/html/body/text()").extract()
        return syllabi
```

But it doesn't work. I understand it's looking for links in that start_url, which is not really what I want it to do. I want to iterate through the sites. Make sense?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is it possible to construct the list of desired URLs beforehand? ex. `urls = ["example.com?cid={}".format(x) for x in range(1, 401)]`? Disclaimer: I have never used Scrapy.

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request
from syllabi.items import SyllabiItem

class SyllabiSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'saylor'
    allowed_domains = ['saylor.org']
    max_cid = 400

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range(self.max_cid):
            yield Request('http://www.saylor.org/site/syllabus.php?cid=%d' % i,
                    callback=self.parse_syllabi)

    def parse_syllabi(self, response):
        syllabi = SyllabiItem()
        syllabi['url'] = response.url
        syllabi['body'] = response.body

        return syllabi
```

Comment: Thanks. Now how do I separate the output into files for each website? When I open a file with a variable name for writing in parse_syllabi, the output for every site goes to the last file, and the other remain empty. Not sure what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: What's going on behind the scenes is magic called [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/).  It would probably be best for you to accept this answer, if it was helpful, and then open a new question.

Comment: It was helpful. I started a new question: Why is Scrapy skipping through loop? Thanks for the help.